# Mandatory documents upload in Sharepoint Folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder

I am new to share point and gained some basics. I have created a new content-type named "Student Project" with Folder as its parent. Inside that folder, I need a couple of mandatory documents such as Final report and Final Presentation.

Are there any ways to ask/force these documents to be uploaded on creating new Student Project?

Answer (score 1):

Create Document Sets instead of folders! For the Document Set content type in your library, configure *Default Content* on the *Document Set Settings* page shown below.

[image]

For more information, see [How to Use the Document Set Content Type in a SharePoint 2013 Document Library](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/03/14/how-to-use-the-document-set-content-type-in-a-sharepoint-2013-document-library.aspx).

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply. How can I automatically ensure whether they have updated the document or it is still empty?

Comment: This is not something SharePoint can do for you! You'll need to develop a script or application that checks these documents and generates the appropriate notification(s). SharePoint has rich APIs that will allow you to programmatically do almost anything.